# Is Visual Studio 2012 CTP going to be a 2012 update?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I tried googling for this information but have found contradictory information. I'm interested in the extended C++11 support for Visual C++ available in the Nov CTP -- is this update going to eventually be a part of a Visual Studio 2012 update, or will it be a part of VS 2014?

Comment: As I understand it, it'll be an update to VS2012. Herb Sutter promised a couple of times that we'll hear more about it in the first half of 2013, so you might have an answer in 19 days.

Comment: Your question belongs on a Microsoft support forum/newsgroup/whatever.

Comment: @Mat, like all the questions with the visual-studio-2012 tag?

Comment: No. Programming questions & questions related to using the tools that go with them are on-topic here. Questions about what a vendor will or will not do with their product aren't.

Comment: Fair enough. However, I asked here because on the support forums there's contradictory information, and no official stance, while here many C++ gurus hang around which might have official information, so it's my last try :/

Comment: Try in chat. The C++ Lounge is pretty active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I read: No. They will be in Visual Studio 2013

See Brian Harry's comment below from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/06/03/visual-studio-2013.aspx

Brian Harry MS 5 Jun 2013 5:36 AM #
@CosmicBagel, Stay tuned for pricing/licensing and upgrade details.  We'll have more on that as we get closer to release.

@Matt Ring, that's more a symptom of how I pull together screenshots.  You won't find that anywhere in the product.  That's a screenshot from a custom process someone had created to show how an organizations that wants a very involved taxonomy might do it.  Out of the box there's only 2 levels: Feature and Backlog Item.  We did talk about using terminology like "Epic" but some in the Scrum community waved us away from that.  Of course you can customize it to be anything you like.

@Greg, Yes, adding checkboxes or some other form of single click way to select files is still on our list of things to do.  We wanted to do it already, we just weren't able to get to it.  Hopefully soon.

@Jesper, I'm not going to dwell on this but clearly there's a lot of interest in C++ and you've articulated your frustration reasonably well so I feel it deserves a response.  First, I don't work on the C++ team and it's a bit tenuous for me to speak for them but I have talked to them about it and can share some thoughts.  They understand that C++ 11 support it important.  They hear the feedback.  They weren't able to get in in VS 2012 (and I think we all regret it) but that's that.  So, they released a CTP a few months after VS 2012 shipped to give people a preview.  There was conversation of putting it into a Visual Studio 2012 Update, however, the feeling was that, given the nature and magnitude of the changes and type of testing cycle an Update affords, the probability of serious regressions was too high.  So the decision was made to roll those capabilities into VS 2013 instead.  As we get more experience with Updates will that kind of risk assessment change - I strongly believe so.  Knowing then what we know now, would we have made that decision differently, I don't know but I doubt it.  You can be confident there will be C++ 11 improvements in VS 2013.  I'm also confident that it won't include everything everyone wants.  I don't think it's hard to say that our C++ compiler is further behind the standard than we want and we are discussing what we can do to change that.